# Depth First Search code doesn't print anything

Tags: c, depth-first-search

I am given a task that asks to print sequence of vertices in DFS. I don't see anything wrong with my code, but it does not print anything.

Below is how the output is supposed to be.

```
Input   Output
6      Vertex 1 is visited
1 4    Vertex 4 is visited
1 6    Vertex 2 is visited
2 4    Vertex 5 is visited
2 5    Vertex 6 is visited
2 6    Vertex 3 is visited
3 4
```

The first  6  here is the number of vertices.

Here is my code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

int m[MAX][MAX], used[MAX];
int i, n, a, b;

void dfs(int v)
{
  int i;
  // Mark the vertex that is visited
  used[v] = 1;
  printf("Vertex %d is visited\n",v);

  // looking for an edge, through which you can get to the vertex that is not visited 

  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    if (m[v][i] && !used[i]) dfs(i);
}

int main(void)
{


  // read input data
  scanf("%d",&n);
  while(scanf("%d %d",&a,&b) == 2)
    m[a][b] = m[b][a] = 1;

  //run dfs from the top 1
  dfs(1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this marked as C++ ? I c C (haha)

Comment: WFM™ https://wandbox.org/permlink/LGA30GxMaXBOeFxN

Comment: @hellow did you change anything?

Comment: @MacInnis That's intentional. The numbers read are indexes into the array; not values to be stored therein.

Comment: Post the input so I can redirect it to stdin.

Comment: i have given a sample input

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see now -- the input and output are interlaced. To reproduce your output, I would have to clean those up. But you already have an answer. In the future, it may be better to post the data in curly braces notation and skip the UI entirely. I find that much easier for MCVE's.

Comment: @Ramsey check it by yourself ;) That's not a good question if you just can follow the link and compare it.

Comment: @hellow i literally stared at it for 5-10mins and couldn't spot the difference))

Comment: Because there is none ;) I just took your code, put it in the online compiler, added the stdin and it worked. Don't know what's wrong :D

Comment: So why does it work with that compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an exit condition for your while loop. scanf just waits for the next 2 numbers. You should modify it, so that when you have finished entering the vertices you continue. Like this:

```
while(scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)) {

    if(a == -1) break;

    m[a][b] = m[b][a] = 1;
}
```

When you enter -1 and something else you exit from the loop.

Comment: Sure there is - the OP is checking the return value from `scanf`. If it's not 2 it will exit the while loop.

Comment: Does not print anything no matter what i enter

Comment: If you input one number scanf just waits for the next one and doesn't proceed.

Comment: @Ramsey Try this input:
3
1 2
2 3
1 3
-1 0

Comment: I assume `n` is supposed to tell you how many coordinates there are in the input file. That's why there's a scanf before the input loop (which should be a for loop)